# Configure private network within a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS KVM host

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization

For learning purpose, I've got one low cost dedicated server to setup kvm host with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I'm completely new to this area.

First of all I want to setup a private network within the host. All the guests including the host will be on this network and would have static ip. The guests should be able to interact with one another by these ip's.

Host has a static public ip. Some of the guests have to be configured with public static ip and domain names. And other guests must be accessible by domain names by ip forwarding(like in lowendbox's).

Please give some pointers or solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first requirement is what should occur by default. Your second requirement, some guests have public static IP, is inconsistent with your first requirement, or do you mean you want both methods at once?

Comment: Yes. All of the guests should be in the private LAN, within the server. Some of them will have public static ip. And others would be NAT'ed through a public ip.

Comment: See if you can extract what you want from [an answer I wrote before](http://askubuntu.com/questions/581771/kvm-create-a-virtual-machine-with-2-bridges-interfaces). However in this case I think you might want to use virbr0 instead of br1. And you will have some specific iptables rules rules to add to your host.